# Add disk on running VM in hyperV

Tags: hyper-v, scsi

I have an Hyper-V VM (generation 1). The VM is running but I need to add a new disk (a .VHD image). I don't want to stop this machine and I would do this while it is still running, but IDE Controller's Add button is disabled. So i only can add SCSI controller; I do and everythng seems OK, but when I connect to the guest VM, I can't see that SCSI disk.
Why? What is wrong with this?

Comment: What OS is your VM running?

Comment: Guest VM are Windows Server 2012, while host is Hyper V server.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have add the new SCSI disk, login in to the VM and then use disk management to do a rescan and the new SCSI disk should appear. you can access disk management through Server Manager.